# Is it possible to extract only the meaningful informantion from Exception.Message

Tags: asp.net, exception

This is what I get when I use  `Exception.Message` :

*System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: **The server can not process the request**. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in . in WebService.ProcessRequestArc... --- End of inner exception stack trace ---*

Is it possible to configure a web application so that exceptions only send the part **in bold** in my example?

Or do you know of any way **to extract only that part**?

Comment: custom errors ? *(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.100).aspx)*; Or `global.asax` - `Application_Error` ?

Comment: @abhitalks how can I use custom errors to only show the part that I want?? or at least to show a shorter version of the message

Comment: Show where? Do you mean that YSOD? If yes, then simply create a  page with exactly what you want to show and specify that page in the customerrors section of your web.config. If no, then please elaborate.

Comment: @abhitalks when an exception is thrown, I send Exception.Message to a notification bar , but Exception.Message sends not only the actual cause of the exception , but it also sends additional information that I don't want to be displayed in the notification bar

Comment: In that case, send this to notification bar: `"The server can not process the request, because " + Exception.Message.Substring(0,Exception.Message.IndexOf(":"))`

Comment: Exception.Message shouldn't have anything with StackTrace or inner exceptions... If you need to parse the string, that's a different question.

Comment: @abhitalks Do you know if Exception messages follow a pattern so that I can use that pattern to get the part that I need from that whole string

Comment: @eddy: Not really. Actually `Message` is just one property of *Exception* class. `HelpLink`, `Source`, `StackTrace`, and `TargetSite` are others. So, `Message` is just a string which I am not sure is following any set pattern. Best you can do is split at first "." or ":" as I showed you above.

Comment: @abhitalks I found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa303450.aspx Please look for : "Configures the error reporting facility" It seems that it has something to do with SOAP services

Comment: @eddy: that is about wse diagnostic tracing. i don't think this applies to you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your problem at first.  To avoid seeing the Stack Trace, you simply had have display `Server.GetLastError().Message`.  On further examination I see that your problem is that exceptions are getting wrapped into a *HttpException*, and the Message from *HttpException* concatenates the method info with the original exception message.

### Solution

In *web.config* you need to add a custom error section.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx"
    mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
```

In *Error.aspx* you can do the following to check if it's an *HttpException*, and if so get the inner exception's message.

```
var ex = Server.GetLastError();
string message;
if (ex != null)
{
    message = ((ex is HttpException || ex is SoapException) && ex.InnerException != null) 
        ? ex.InnerException.Message : ex.Message;
}
else
{
    message = "An error has occurred.";
}

Response.Write(message);
```

On your page you just want to show **Server.GetLastError().Message**.

Here is the before and after for a divide by zero error:

- **Before**: Default.aspx(4): error CS0020: Division by constant zero
- **After**: Attempted to divide by zero.

For *SoapException* to actually have the InnerException property not be null, then you need to throw a SoapException with the actual exception inside.

Here are some links from MSDN regarding the customErrors section and error handling:

- [customErrors Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Complete Example for Error Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I need to get a part of Exception.Message, and that part should not include the call stack or information about the inner exceptions.

Comment: I see.  I updated my answer a bit, but You either need to throw a soap exception, or parse string like suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `Message` property of an exception does not follow any pattern. In particular, the `Message` property will be different depending on the current culture settings (language).

But even if you are only concerned about a single language, you should never depend on anything in the `Message` property. It simply contains whatever the developer who threw the exception thinks you might want to see.

In particular, it does *not* contain anything that you should display to your users!